# R - compute the convolution of 2 multidimensional continuous densities with the help of the fft function

Tags: r, fft, convolution

I need to compute a convolution of 2 independent multidimensional continuous densities, given only by their numerical values on a grid.

To understand how to compute convolutions, I am trying to compute some simple examples using the fft function in R, however, it is not working correctly. For example I wanted to compute a convolution of 2 independent standard normal rv's, the code below.

```
#values from a standard normal density
eps <- 1e-1
points <- seq(-5,5, by = eps)    
x <- dnorm(points)    
y <- dnorm(points)

#padded values x, y with 0 to use fft function
xPad <- c(rep(0, length(y)),  x)    
yPad <- c(y, rep(0, length(x)))    
zPad <- fft(fft(xPad)*fft(yPad), inverse  = 'TRUE')/length(fft(xPad)*fft(yPad))    
plot(Re(zPad))    
max(Re(zPad))    
dnorm(0, sd = sqrt(2))
```

My questions:

1) Why do I have to multiply the result with the eps value? This is probably the consequence of the fact that the densities are continuous and not discrete.

2) The plot looks like a normal distribution splitted in two halfs. How do I know which value belongs to which x from the interval [-5,5]?

My expectation would be following. Take 2 sequences of N(0,1) density values from [-5,5], compute the convolution, the result is a sequence of N(0,2) density values from [-5,5].

Any explanation of the logic behind the application of FFT or help with the multidimensional case are most welcome.